# How to use SendKeys(Protractor) command in the text box that is located in an iframe?

Tags: protractor

```
    iframe:ElementFinder=element(by.xpath("//iframe"));
    firstName:ElementFinder=element(by.xpath("//label[text()='First Name']/following::input[1]"));
    DOB:ElementFinder=element(by.xpath(".//label[text()='Date of Birth']/following::input[1]"));
       async fillPersonalInformation() {
        console.log("one");
        browser.switchTo().frame(this.iframe.getWebElement());
        console.log("hello");
        await this.firstName.sendKeys("hii");
        console.log("hello1");
        await this.DOB.sendKeys("02/02/1991")
        console.log("hello2");
        Utils.logger("Logo is displayed")
        console.log("end");
     }
```

**My test passed successfully and no text is written in the text box**

[image]

**DOM**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your HTML also here

Comment: @BharathKumarS - Updated in the questions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK all browser's methods return a promise, so try `await browser.switchTo().frame(this.iframe.getWebElement());`

Comment: I have tried the above code but it also not help me to achieve the task